# How to check if a coordinate lies in a certain area?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, coordinates

i need to create code which allows you to check if the coordinate you enter lies within a certain area. So far i have this:

```
import random
import math
import pylab
import numpy    
pylab.close("all")                                                      #All import statements
x = [(random.randint(-50,50)) for i in range(10)]               #Creating list of x coordinates
y = [(random.randint(-50,50)) for j in range(10)]               #Creating list of y coordinates
array=zip(x,y)                                                          #Creating an array by combining the x and y coordinates
print array             

counter = 0                                 #Start of 1c, resetting counter
for i, j in array:                              #Telling what to inspect
        if 35**2 <= (i**2+j**2) <= 65**2:                   #Conditions for the coordinates to fall within 15 pixels of a circle with radius 50
                counter+= 1                         #If conditions met then add 1 to counter
n=(1.0*counter/7000)*100                            #Calculating percentage of coordinates in the region
print "on average", n, "% of the locations in the array fall in this region"    #Print result, end of part 1c


name = raw_input('type a coordinate location: ')                #Start of 1d, python input result
for i, j in name:
    if i in name in array:   
        if 35**2 <= (i**2+j**2) <= 65**2:
            print "warning, your chosen location falls near the edge of the circle"
    else:
         print "coordinate does not exist"
```

but at the moment i get an error message saying 'need more than 1 value to unpack' referring to the 'name = raw_input('type a coordinate location: ')' line. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Please, don't use 1-letter variable names. For starters, they are not easily discernible in a code. And meaningful names make code much easier to read.
Of course, the only meaningful 1-letter variable name I may think of are x, y and z

Answer (score 0):

name is a string. you cannot use

`for i, j in name:`

you need to break it first to values, and create a tuple.

maybe something like this:

n = (name.split(',')[0],name.split(',')[1]) - assuming the coordinates are separated by ','

Comment: so where would that line of code go? and would it replace 'for i, j in name:'

Comment: that line of code is just a demonstration. you should replace `name` with `n`, but use a better name than `n`. it comes before the for loop of course...

Comment: ok and its purpose is to split what is entered to actual values? Using this how would the user have to input the coordinate when prompted. would they enter it like 'x,y'?

Answer (score 0):

"raw_input" returns a string. You need to split() it and convert numbers to integers